# insertElementAtSelection stopped working

Tags: javascript, thunderbird-addon

In my Thunderbird Addon called [PasteHyperlink](https://addons.mozilla.org/seamonkey/addon/406802), I have a routine that inserts an html element into the Message Compose Window.

This used to work in Thunderbird, but now I get this js error:

```
Error: TypeError: thiseditor.insertElementAtSelection is not a function
```

However, it seems that `thiseditor` gets defined because it doesn't launch the alert.

Here is the function's code which I've reduced to the basic functionality:

```
var thiseditor = gMsgCompose.editor;
if (!thiseditor){ alert("Dude, the gMsgCompose.editor is broken") };    
let link = thiseditor.document.createElement("a");  
link.setAttribute("href", "http://stackoverflow.com");

link.textContent = "Display Text"; 
thiseditor.insertElementAtSelection(link, false);
```

[MDN has this documentation](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHTMLEditor.html#insertElementAtSelection()), but I can't find anything anywhere that talks about why this is broken or what changed under the hood in Thunderbird 45.

Why did this quit working, and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I figured it out.  I changed this:

```
var thiseditor = gMsgCompose.editor;
```

to this:

```
var thiseditor = gMsgCompose.editor.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHTMLEditor);
```

Funny thing, it worked the first way for quite a long time.  I don't know what changed in Thunderbird, though.